# Advapi32 LogonUser Impersonate And WebClient con Network Credential

Tags: c#, webservice, windows

Hace una semana me encargaron hacer un proyecto de comunicación con un Webservice cuyas peticiones requerían de un certificado. Para obtener ese certificado se me facilitó un usuario windows junto con su contraseña y una ruta de red donde estaba ubicado ese certificado. El certificado está en un servidor (servidor A) y la aplicación que hace todo en otro (servidor B).

Para autenticarme como ese usuario, emplee la funcionalidad **Impersonate** empleando el token devuelto por la función **LogonUser** de **Advapi32**

Posteriormente, me comentó mi jefa de usar un objeto **WebClient** con una **NetworkCredential** para obtener el certificado. Los permisos de acceso de la carpeta de red para este usuario son de acceso total para esa carpeta.

Revisando un poco la documentación del método **OpenRead** del **WebClient**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/781fwaz8(v=vs.110).aspx habla sobre que ese método realiza una operación **RETR**. Por lo que he visto, **OpenRead** hace una copia del fichero de donde está almacenado a donde se está llamando. Sería como copiar del Servidor A al Servidor B.

Por tema de permisos, me devuelve todo el rato un **AccessDenied**.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Es seguro usar **Impersonate** o **WebClient**? También he visto que es fácil esnifar las peticiones de un weblclient.

Aquí un ejemplo del código que uso para ambos casos:

A) **WebClient**

```
 WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient ();
 myWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential 
 (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings [ "fileServerUser" ], pass, 
 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings [ "fileServerDom" ] );

 // Open a stream to point to the data stream coming from the Web resource.

 using ( Stream myStream = myWebClient.OpenRead ( "path" ) )
 {
       MemoryStream fileOnMemory = new MemoryStream ();
       using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader ( myStream ) )
       {
             myStream.CopyTo ( fileOnMemory );
             reader.Close ();
       }
 }
```

B) **Impersonate**

```
[DllImport ( "advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true )]
 public static extern bool LogonUser (string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, 
string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

 if ( Utilities.Network.NetworkUtilities.LogonUser ( userName, 
      Utils.Consts.DOMAIN, userPass, logonType, providerType, ref token ) )
 {
         using ( WindowsImpersonationContext person = new WindowsIdentity ( token ).Impersonate () )
         {

             //Do something
         }
  }
```

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. Me parece que ésta pregunta se basa en opiniones y por lo tanto puede ser cerrada

Comment: @FederHico Estoy preguntando que opción es más segura y porqué, no creo que sea cuestión de opiniones, ¿no?

Comment: A mi entender, las preguntas deben versar sobre problemas específicos que no se pueden resolver, no sobre si x es mejor que y . Sin embargo todo está sujeto a revisión de los moderadores, así que si tu pregunta continua abierta, u obtiene respuesta, quiere decir que el equivocado soy yo y la pregunta no es "Basada en Opiniones". Slds

Comment: @FederHico Si parece que estoy preguntando por opiniones disculpa pues mi intención es obtener una respuesta concreta, si puede inducir a error lo que intento expresar o te parece que esté "mal" pues se reformula la pregunta pero yo creo que es bastante interesante

Comment: Hola Pablo, si los dos ejemplos que publicaste funcionan, entonces __no existe ningún problema__ que resolver. Si existe una norma oficial sobre el lenguaje que estás usando, esa debería ser tu fuente de consulta. Si tu organización ha implementado alguna política sobre buenas prácticas, esa debería ser tu fuente. Revisa [esta guía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @toledano Si te fijas en mi pregunta, con webclient me da error de Access Denied, por tema de permisos y de momento no hemos conseguido resolver el porqué. En cambio con impersonate va perfecto.

Comment: Entonces, por favor edita tu pregunta y clarifica tu problema. Para que quede aún más claro, limita tu pregunta al problema de WebClient y descarta toda referencia a Impersonate y tu solicitud sobre buenas prácticas, si eso es lo que te interesa. Adicionalmente, agrega un __[mcve]__.

Comment: @toledano no creo que sea necesario, mi pregunta se basa en una comparativa. He estado investigando con webclient y con impersonate pero no entiendo el porque me falla con webclient. Es por ello que aludo a la función de Impersonate añadiendo su correspondiente código porque me parece que ayuda bastante a la explicación de la pregunta.

Comment: Saludos Pablo, bienvenido a SOes, precisamente si te lanza error, edita la pregunta agregando los detalles tales como los pasos que realizas hasta donde te da el error. Tener una pregunta de la manera que tienes actualmente se basa en opiniones, desde el título, ese "vs" ya inclina la balanza para ese lado. Tómate un tiempo para darle forma que las respuestas solucionen ese "no entiendo el por qué me falla con webclient". Por cierto, ¡bienvenido a SOes!

Comment: @fredyfx Buenas Fredy, Ya está editada pero no entiendo el por qué se me sigue diciendo que mi pregunta se basa en opiniones. Quizás sigue sin estar bien planteada, puede ser. Pero también me gustaría obtener alguna respuesta en cuanto a seguridad sobre impersonate. Sino haré otra pregunta sobre ese tema porque he intentado englobar las dos cosas en una misma pregunta por ahorrar posts.